# Automatic install NetBSD ISO

Tags: netbsd

Is there some form of automated NetBSD installation?

I would like to automate this manual process:
https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-exinst.html

But I found no examples.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is a i386 or amd64 Qemu or Xen VM, then yes -- [Anita](http://www.gson.org/netbsd/anita/) tool exists for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, compiling you can do it.

You can make one script to put all directories and all stuff and prepare the installation, more interesting, NetBSD comes with build.sh

build.sh is one script to help you at compiling or cross-compiling NetBSD

You can do a live iso just typing something like build.sh make live iso

I don't remember the exact option, but you can see it here:

iso-image     Create a NetBSD installation CD-ROM image in the
                   RELEASEDIR/images directory.  The CD-ROM file system will
                   have a layout as described in release(7).

https://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/BUILDING

https://wiki.netbsd.org/tutorials/how_to_build_netbsd-current/#index7h1

The other option is just copy a NetBSD installation to other disk, but this may fail if hardware is different and not's a good choice, anyway dd can do this

PD: You should see the source code of sysinstall.